# Symfony2 Redirection loop

Tags: php, ssl, symfony-2.3

I am using Symfony2 and for ssl URLS I have define my routes as follows:

```
registration_join:
   pattern: /join
   defaults: {_controller: UserBundle:Registration:join}
   requirements:
      _scheme: https
```

In this case when I click join link then it is continuously redirecting and error comes

**error : This webpage has a redirect loop**

When I remove

```
registration_join:
   pattern: /join
   defaults: {_controller: UserBundle:Registration:join}
   requirements:
     _scheme: http
```

Then it work fine

In both above cases I hit the url with

```
https://domain/join
```

Comment: What does yout controller look like?

Comment: On first line of my controller Action I have write exit(); but it's not exit it is redirecting ....

Comment: Since updating to the latest version I have this problem too. Any actions that existed work. Any new ones give me a redirect loop. Not related to https

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with firewall / access control configuration. Make sure in particular that you have something like this in `security.yml`:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/join, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

For more details on this section: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html